# How to add a domain to k3s certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, kubernetes, k3s

When trying to access a k3s Kubernetes cluster that's running on another machine, I get the following error message:

```
E0204 19:13:27.185678    8066 proxy_server.go:147]
Error while proxying request:
  tls: failed to verify certificate:
    x509: certificate is valid for kubernetes, kubernetes.default,
    kubernetes.default.svc, kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local,
    localhost, node1, not node1.lan
```

`node1` is the hostname of the machine serving as the master node in the k3s cluster. However, hosts on my LAN are suffixed with `.lan`, so `node1` is available at `node1.lan`.

I believe I am receiving the error above because the certificate generated by k3s doesn't include node1.lan. I would like to modify/replace the certificate with one that also includes node1.lan.

I have already tried [the instructions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/) documented on the k8s site. However, as I am using k3s not k8s, some details differ.

I'm quite a k8s amateur, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: @ James Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem.If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for the community or upvote if the answer has some useful information.

Comment: Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem.If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for the community or upvote if the answer has some useful information.

Comment: @ James If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for the community or upvote if the answer has some useful information

Comment: I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If yes, please upvote and accept the answer. If not, I am happy to assist further.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the certificate presented by the k3s cluster is not valid for the domain name **node1.lan**. This is likely because the certificate was generated for a different domain name, such as **kubernetes.default.svc**. Because the subject name in the Kubernetes cluster certificate that you wish to monitor differs from the endpoint that you have set in the Kubernetes target configuration.

Put the IP into the **kube config** it works just fine, follow this [blog](https://docs.microfocus.com/doc/Containerized_Operations_Bridge/2023.05/CertSubjectNameMismatch) by Micro focus for more details.

**Workaround:1**

Rotate certificates with custom CA helps to add a domain to K3s certificates

As per this [doc](https://docs.k3s.io/cli/certificate#rotating-client-and-server-certificates) by K3s

- To rotate custom CA certificates, use the k3s certificate **rotate-ca subcommand**. Updated files must be staged into a temporary directory, loaded into the datastore and k3s must be restarted on all nodes to use the updated certificates.
- By doing this, all cluster certificates including server certificates with the new domains will be generated.
- For complete certificate management across the cluster, use custom CA rotation.

**Workaround:2**

To add domain to k3s certificate follow below steps:

- Create a new certificate that includes additional domains
- Create a certificate signing request (CSR) and edit the CSR to include the domain name.
- Submit that k3s Certificate Authority to get it signed with the help of CSR
- Restart the k3s service on all nodes to access the k3s Kubernetes cluster without getting the error message

Refer to [Setting up your own K3S home cluster](https://www.fullstaq.com/knowledge-hub/blogs/setting-up-your-own-k3s-home-cluster) BY BAS BREMER for more information.